# Last entered char to lower case or upper case

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a code. Input character, program stops when I input full stop (.).
So, i want to change my last entered char to lower case if user input upper case, or upper case if user input lower case. So my problem is how to change upper case to lower or lower to upper. I dont know how to find last index.

Example:[g j g k . K] or  [k j f G . g]

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String character = input.nextLine();

    while (true) {
        String character1 = input.nextLine();
        if (character1.equals(".")) {
            break;
```

So, i just made that my progaram stop when user input full stop, and i dont know how to change last entered char to lower or upper case!

Comment: Hint: There is a `Character.toUpperCase` and a `Character.toLowerCase`

Comment: Can you share some sample input and the output you'd like to get for it? It would make the question a lot clearer.

Comment: @GBlodgett Yeah man, but i dont know how to initalize last entered char. As i said, user input random chars and when user input full stop, program need to convert last index to upper case if it's a lower case or lower case if it's a upper case

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry, i will do it now!

Comment: Also note that you are reading a whole line to `character`. I think you wanted `char character = input.next().charAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String character ="C".toLowerCase();
```

if you mean `String` and not `char`...

Comment: I cant make code like that, because user input random strings/chars. So i need to find last entered string, check if he is upper and chage to lower, or if he is lower chage it to upper.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you try change input but it is not possible. You have to print every character on output.

You can try something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Char lastChar = '';

while (true) {
    String character1 = input.nextLine();
    if (character1.equals(".")) {
        if(isBig(lastChar)) {
            print(lowerCase(lastChar));
        } else {
            print(upperCase(lastChar));
        }          
        break;
    }
    print(lastChar);
    lastChar = character1;
}
```

Comment: Ok, try `Character lastChar = '';` I don't know Java so much. But my algorithm is right.

Answer (score 0):

Build around the following.

The first two check if the character is upper case or lower case. Next two convert two upper case and lower case respectively.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char)

So, it would go something like this. It only converts the last character if it is a letter. If you need the last letter and not the last character, you can easily modify it.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("");
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

    while(true){
        String token = scanner.next();
        if( token.equals(".") ){
            break;
        }
        characters.add(token.charAt(0));
    }
    for( int i = 0 ; i < characters.size() - 1 ; i++){
        System.out.print(characters.get(i));
    }
    Character lastCharacter = characters.get( characters.size() - 1 );
    if( Character.isUpperCase( lastCharacter ) ) {
        lastCharacter = Character.toLowerCase(lastCharacter);
    }else if( Character.isLowerCase( lastCharacter )) {
        lastCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(lastCharacter);
    }
    System.out.println( lastCharacter );
```